# Why does Festival / Scheme stop speaking?

Tags: scheme, text-to-speech, festival

I have a Festival / Scheme file `speakall.scm` with the contents:

```
(voice_kal_diphone)
(tts "file1.txt" nil)
(tts "file2.txt" nil)
```

If I ask Festival to play either file1.txt or file2.txt, it reads the entire file.  However, when combined into the above, and run with

```
festival -b speakall.scm
```

it craps out early in file2.txt.

I'm guessing some buffer is filling somewhere and not emptying.

File1 has 43 words, and file2 has 50 words.

How can I get it to speak all of both files (and any others I might add)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tts` synthesizes audio in async mode which is probably not a good idea. I would use `tts_file` instead.

```
 (tts_file "file1.txt" 'fundamental)
```